# Issue with mobx + react can't do computed method due to diffrent wrappers on variable from mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have an api call which nicely get a status code and data value, then I assign this data to mobx variable. Then I tried to do computed field but it gave me an error, I consoled logged what's going on and what it showed me that api call indeed gives a good value, but when I assign array to mobx `this.items` at the end it has hundreds of wrappers and it can't  do any array methods on it. How to solve it ? Thank you!

```
import { makeObservable, observable, action, computed } from 'mobx'

class Products{
    items = [];

    constructor(rootStore){
        this.rootStore = rootStore;
        this.api = this.rootStore.api.products

        makeObservable(this, {
            items: observable,
            getAll: action,
            getPopular: computed
        })
    }

     async getAll(){
        let res = await this.api.getAll();
        console.log(res.data) // normal
        if(res.status === 'success')
            this.items = res.data;
        console.log(this.items); // with diffrent wrapper therfore can't do a computed method
    }

    get getPopular(){
        return this.items.filter(el => el.popular)
    }
}

export default Products;
```

[image: picture]

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: That's what MobX does to your observable data under the hood, but an observable MobX array still has all the regular array methods, e.g. `filter`. What error are you getting?